# What does %c mean in GCC inline assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, xen

I am trying to understand this inline assembly code which comes from `_hypercall0` [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git;a=blob_plain;f=arch/x86/include/asm/xen/hypercall.h;hb=HEAD).

```
asm volatile ("call hypercall_page+%c[offset]" \
        : "=r" (__res) \
        : [offset] "i" (__HYPERVISOR_##name * sizeof(hypercall_page[0])) \
        : "memory", "edi", "esi", "edx", "ecx", "ebx", "eax")
```

I am having trouble finding information on what `%c` in the first line means.  I did not find any information in the most obvious section of the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), which explains `%[name]`, but not `%c[name]`. Is there any other place I should look at?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [GCC internals documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Output-Template.html#Output-Template):

> `%c*digit*' can be used to substitute an
>   operand that is a constant value
>   without the syntax that normally
>   indicates an immediate operand.

Answer (score 2):

Check the assembly output (with `gcc -S`, or maybe disassemble the object file) and it may be clearer.

My guess is that it stands for **constant**.  `hypercall_page` looks like a table of instructions that each do a syscall. Maybe this will generate a `call hypercall_page + {constant based on the expression given}`, essentially having computed the address of this offset at compile time.

As an aside, this `__HYPERVISOR##name` stuff really reminds me of the `__NR_name_of_syscall` type convention you see for syscalls in Linux's <asm/unistd.h> and similar places.