# GCC extended asm, struct element offset encoding

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, i386

I am trying to write a small piece of my code in GCC style extended asm (x86-64 target) and am having trouble encoding struct offsets.

I have a `struct s` with a member `size_t a[]`, a pointer to such a struct and an index both of which are generated within the asm block.

Now I need to address that element in asm

```
asm (
    "mov %[displ](%[s], %[index], 8), %%rbx"
    : [s] "+r" (s)
    , [index] "+r" (i)
    : "memory", "cc", "rax", "rbx"
);
```

How can I encode `displ` into the asm block? Passing `offsetof(struct s, a)` as an immediate prefixes it with `$` and generates invalid assembly.

```
asm (
    "mov %[displ](%[s], %[index], 8), %%rbx"
    : [s] "+r" (s)
    , [index] "+r" (i)
    : [displ] "i" (offsetof(struct s, a))
    : "memory", "cc", "rax", "rbx"
);
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `s.a[index]` in the C code?

Comment: Because the above is a smaller example and in reality the asm block is large, contains far more instructions around and several jumps. And because this isn't the first occasion where I have needed that effect.

Comment: Ok, if it is a large block of assembly, I would consider putting that in a separate .asm file and let the C code compute and pass the parameters needed. There is no way you can get the address calculations more efficient in assembly, so to me it seems like a complication we could live without.

Comment: Well, the struct is used in both C and asm code, so I need to have the same offsets across both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It actually *is* possible, using the `%c...` operand modifier:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct s
{
  int a, b;
};

int foo (struct s *s, int i)
{
  int r;
  asm (
       "movl %c[displ](%[s],%[index],8), %[r]\n\t"
       : [r] "=r" (r)
       : [s] "r" (s) , [index] "r" ((uintptr_t)i),
         [displ] "e" (offsetof(struct s, b))
       :
       );

  return r;
}
```

Thanks where thanks is due - found that [here](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/a-brief-tutorial-on-gcc-inline-asm). There's [a gcc mailing list posting](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/1999-10n/msg00488.html) referring to this as well; the keywords there are "output substitution".
The stackoverflow posting [What does %c mean in GCC inline assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672900/what-does-c-mean-in-gcc-inline-assembly-code) also has an explanation about `%c` in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to use Intel syntax. GCC, of course, can generate insn like `mov off(base, index, scale)`, but does this on the level of whole `MEM` RTL expressions, i.e. not having offset, base, etc like individual operands.

So, Intel syntax, compile the following with `gcc -c -masm=intel x.c`:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct s
{
  int a, b;
};

int foo (struct s *s, int i)
{
  int r;
  asm (
       "mov %[r], dword ptr [%[s]+%[index]*8 + %[displ]] "
       : [r] "=r" (r)
       : [s] "r" (s) , [index] "r" (i),
         [displ] "e" (offsetof(struct s, b))
       :
       );

  return r;
}
```

Comment: I knew about that, but it makes my code incompatible with some device driver includes (which have AT&T style inline asm) that I have in the same file. Yes, I know I can split them thus forfeiting the point of optimised code.

Comment: You can switch back and forth between syntax types using `.intel_syntax` and `.att_syntax`.